# How to save a PDF being displayed in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I am looking at a website (internal to my company so cannot share) in Google Chrome. When I click on a particular link, it opens up a PDF file in a new window. (It's javascript, not a plain link, so I can't click "Save as" to save to disk instead of opening.)

When I go to save the PDF to disk, it tries to reload the PDF from the webserver rather than just saving the PDF in memory to disk. And in this case the webserver does not allow a 2nd fetch of the URL; it fails with a 404 Not Found.

If I use Firefox it just saves what it has in memory to disk, so I have a workaround by using another browser. But is there a way to get Chrome to save what it has in memory?

Comment: I believe this need should be taken up with your company's ID department.

Comment: In an ideal world, yes, but it leads to all sorts of bureaucratic standstills; this isn't the only issue -- invalid self-signed HTTPS certificates, claims of only working on Internet Explorer, etc. So that's not practical. I am interested in the exact question I asked.